# MySQL columns POINT vs 2x DECIMAL (lat & lng) performance

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a new data model for a project which will quickly contain many rows. In this regard I am considering if I should use MySQL `POINT` or `DECIMAL` to store lat/lng position indications.

I know that not choosing `POINT` will make it harder for me to make geo-calculations, since I don't get the new built-in geo functions available for `DECIMAL` fields, but I can live without them - since geo-selects will be only with a outer-box model like `WHERE (lat BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AND (lng BETWEEN 0 AND 5)`

I am, however, worried about database size - **and more importantly: Query time/performace**.

1. Is POINT a fixed-length field like DECIMAL?
2. Will it be more efficient to use POINT or 2x DECIMAL for lat/lng?

Answer (score 0):

I use VARCHAR to store lat/lng. MySql isn't very good with math functions, so I store lat/lng like a VARCHAR and php scripts (or java scripts or perl scripts or what you want) make the calculations...

Comment: Sorry, but that really isn't a viable option for me, because 1) VARCHAR is not an efficient field for a large dataset like this, and 2) VARCHAR with combined lat/lng does not allow for proper selects based on lat/lng (I'd that's what you suggest). Either way, your answer doesn't help with my questions from above :-( Thanka for the effort anyway :-)